# Serious Error on reading SD card in WinCE MFC

Tags: mfc, windows-ce, sd-card

In WinCE 6.0, my application reading SD card, sometimes raise an error message box:

> "Application xxx.exe encountered a serious error and must be shut
>   down"

Then my application will be terminated by the system.
It depends on the quality of SD card, not every SD card would cause this error.
How can I catch/avoid this kind of error and keep my application alive?

Comment: First of all: Debug. Where does this error occurs. Who is causing it. Look into the call stack!

Comment: Thanks, anyway. I hope I can run debug mode at that physical machine. However, the manufacture did not set an USB or somewhat connection for  software debugging. I will keep trying to negotiate with them.

Comment: Just use remote debugging. It is real easy!